# How to get MIFARE access condition in Android

Tags: nfc, mifare

The way I do it is to read the data from block 3 and select the proper bytes from the result to get the access condition (e.g.:FF 07 80 69)

In this way, if I don't have keyA or keyB, I can not get the data from block 3.

Is there another way to get the access condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the only way to read any of the blocks of MIFARE Classic is to first authenticate with Key A or Key B. There is no shortcut.

Comment: Thank you very much! if don't have keyA or keyB,means unkonw access condition and unknow read/write other block shoud use keyA/keyB?

Comment: Yes, but if you don't have Key A and Key B, you cannot read or write anyway.